# SE sites are now allowed to set banner with their official AI generated content policy, is this community interested in such banner?

Tags: discussion

SE recently created an option for individual SE site to have banner that [highlights the site's policy on AI generated answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera?cb=1).

Since AI generated answers can lead to people using them as a content mills it might make sense to put the following banner on our site.

```
**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more
```

There are also other options such as requiring citation for the AI generated content.

Before requesting the banner we should discuss this on our meta site. Please feel free to voice your opinion on this possibility.